# Database won't update values with php form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to make a small form that can update a value from my database, but it just won't work.. I've read all different questions and answers on this topic but I can't manage to get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
    include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");

    $u = "";
    $country = "";

    if(isset($_GET["u"])){
        $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
    } else {
        header("location: index.html");
        exit(); 
    }

//A lot of other code for other queries

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND activated='1'";
        $user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

        mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE  SET country='$_POST[country]' WHERE username='$_POST[u]' ");

        if($result){
        echo "succesful";

        }

        else {
        echo "ERROR";
        }

        ?>

        <form method="post" /> 
            <p><span>Country: </span><input type="text" name="country" id="country" value="<?php echo $country; ?>"></p>
             <p><input class="Submit" name="submit"type="submit"  value="Save">

        </form>
```

Anyone who can see what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Update what? You forgot the table name.

Comment: you've a major SQL injection issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$country = $_POST['country'];

mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE users SET country='$country' WHERE username='$u' ");
```

You did not mention the table in update statement. and `$_POST` name must be quoted in `[]`.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Do you know how I can redirect the user to a page when updating was succesfull?

Comment: Welcome if you are satisfied please accept the answer. Yes you can redirect.

Comment: Yep I did! How should I do that..?

Comment: Try this `if($my_sqli_query){ header('Location:index.php'); } else { echo "Error: The column is not updated."; }`         after the update query.

Comment: Doesn't work.. It does not redirect after updating and the error message is above my form all the time.

Comment: try using `mysql_affected_rows()` with conditions like `if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1){` or `if(mysql_affected_rows() > 1 || mysql_affected_rows() < 1){`

Answer (score 1):

The table name is missing in your update query:

```
mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE table SET country='{$_POST['country']}' WHERE username='{$_POST['u']}' ");
```

Comment: and array key must be in quotes as well...

Comment: You should really not do that. Take a look at prepared statements.